# node.js require all files in a folder

Tags: javascript

i have a project in my folder containing .js files each containg `exports.handler = {...}`.
Now in my index.js i require them all and use them like this:

```
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');

const skillBuilder = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom();

exports.handler = skillBuilder
  .addRequestHandlers(
    require('./handler/Random').handler,
    require('./handler/Repeat').handler,
    require('./handler/LaunchRequest').handler,
    require('./handler/Help').handler,
    require('./handler/Exit').handler,
    require('./handler/SessionEndedRequest').handler
  )
  .lambda()
```

I plan on creating many more of these handlers and was wondering if there is a way to loop over all files in './handler' and add them all. the `addRequestHandlers` can be called for each handler individually and the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to loop over all files in the `./handlers` directory (or in any directory too). This is done through the [`fs.readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) function:

```
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');
const skillBuilder = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom();
const fs = require('fs');

var handler = skillBuilder;
var handlerDir = './handlers/';

// Iterate over handlers in that directory
try {
    var files = fs.readdirSync(handlerDir);
    for(var i in files) {
        if(files[i].endsWith('.js')) {
            // This is a JavaScript file
            handler = handler
                .addRequestHandlers(
                    require(handlerDir + files[i]).handler
                );
        }
    };

    exports.handler = handler.lambda();
} catch(err) {
    // Handle errors here
}
```

Comment: doesn't work. the iteration goes through all the js files, but they are not in the final export. could it be, that it is exported before the callback function is called?

Comment: The call to the `readdir` function is asynchronous, so yes, the JS files would not be exported before the iteration. I updated my answer, so the export will happen **after** iterating through the files.

Comment: thanks it worked(although you forgot do declare the variable `i`)